# Last iteration for enhanced for loop

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to loop over an Iterable using the enhanced for loop but I am not able to determine when is the last value being processed.

```
     public void apply(Tuple key, 
                    GlobalWindow w, 
                    Iterable<Tuple5<String, Long, List<Lane>, Long, Long>> itrbl, 
                    Collector<Tuple5<String, Long, List<Lane>, Long, Long>> clctr) throws Exception {
       long cachedUmlaufSekunde = 0;
       long currentUmlaufSekunde = 0;
       long maxUmlaufSekunde = 0;
       for(Tuple5 tuple:itrbl) {
          maxUmlaufSekunde = (long)tuple.getField(4);
          currentUmlaufSekunde = ((long)tuple.getField(1)/10)*10;
          if(currentUmlaufSekunde == (cachedUmlaufSekunde + 10)) {
            cachedUmlaufSekunde =  currentUmlaufSekunde;
          } else {
              cachedUmlaufSekunde = cachedUmlaufSekunde + 10;
          }
       }
```

Many questions related to this topic suggest using the function **iterator.hasNext()** to determine the last element but I guess using something like

```
    itrbl.iterator.hasNext();
```

within the for loop is not a solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know when the last element is being iterated over, then use the `iterator` form in a standard `for` loop instead.  The enhanced-`for` will run through *all* elements of an iterable, and it's not possible to discern when the end is.

```
for(Iterator<Tuple5> tuplIter = iterbl.iterator(); tuplIter.hasNext(); ) {
    Tuple5 tupl = tuplIter.next();

    // check for next
    if(!tuplIter.hasNext()) {
        // logic for processing the last tuple
    }
}
```